# WRAP span-tag around existing INPUT-tag

Tags: javascript, class, radio-button, prepend

I have a checklist which contains about 50 Radiobutton groups. Each group has 3 buttons with the values: Yes No N/A. These groups are created using a form-tool of which I have no to little control over.

I need to prepend a -tag to all Radio-buttons with the value "Yes" in EVERY single group in the form. Using only vanilla javascript.

I have tried to create a javascript that can sort through all radiobutton groups. And I have tried to append the finding to an array that I can use to loop through for the prepend action.

Note that ID and NAME is generated for me so I cannot know in advance what the groupnames are.

```
console.log('start')
//var span = document.getElementById("span_id");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 console.log('a:',inputs)
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (inputs[i].defaultValue == 'yes') {
       var idd = inputs[i].id

      var parent = document.getElementById(idd).parentNode;
            var p = document.createElement("p");
            var span = document.createElement("span");
            //parent.append(p);
            parent.prepend(span);
    }
}
}

getCheckedValue()
```

I have a fiddle with the most updated code here: https://jsfiddle.net/y4vLbtmw/54/

problem is I cannot get the SPAN-tag to wrap around the existing tag. It only appends before or after. How do I put the tag like this: < span class="green" >[existing code]< / span >

Do I copy the exisiting tag, delete it and then re-insert it between the new span ? or is there another way ?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the Inner HTML of the parent div in that way

`parent.innerHTML = "<span> " + parentHTML + "</span>";`

```
function getCheckedValue() {
console.log('start')
//var span = document.getElementById("span_id");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 console.log('a:',inputs)
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (inputs[i].defaultValue == 'yes') {
       var idd = inputs[i].id

      var parent = document.getElementById(idd).parentNode();
      parentHTML = parent.innerHTML;
      parent.innerHTML = "<span> " + parentHTML + "</span>";
            //var p = document.createElement("p");
            //var span = document.createElement("span");
            //parent.append(p);
            //parent.prepend(span);
    }
}
}

getCheckedValue()
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a while but I finally found a solution.

```
function getCheckedValue(newColor,newValue) {

//var span = document.getElementById("span_id");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
    if (newValue.localeCompare(inputs[i].value) == 0) {

       var idd = inputs[i].id
   console.log('value:',newValue,inputs[i].value,idd)
      elementToWrap = document.getElementById(idd);
            divWrapper = document.createElement("span");
      divWrapper.setAttribute("class", newColor);

      wrap_single(elementToWrap, divWrapper);
    }
}
}

function wrap_single(el, wrapper) {
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, el);
    wrapper.appendChild(el);
}
let divWrapper;
let elementToWrap;

//Run 

getCheckedValue('green','yes');
getCheckedValue('red','no');
getCheckedValue('yellow','n/a');
```

Thank you for your input

Answer (score 0):

Can’t you store the innerHTML and then write the span open tag + html + span close tag?